# Динамическое обновление контента c помощью ajax через GET запрос на Django

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, ajax, django

Мне нужно, что бы новые сообщения от пользователя обновлялись по мере их поступления, без обновления страницы. Пока получилось добиться только того, что передаваемые данные поступаю просто как string, а не query_set. Ну по крайней мере мне так это видится. Что изменить в коде, что бы все заработало корректно?

utils.py

```
class ObjectMessageMixin:
    model = None
    modelForm = None
    template = None

    def get(self, request, chat_id):
        try:
            chat = self.model.objects.get(id=chat_id)
            if request.user in chat.members.all():
                chat.message_set.filter(is_read=False).exclude(author=request.user).update(is_read=True)
            else:
                chat = None
        except Chat.DoesNotExist:
            chat = None
        ctx = {}
        ctx['user'] = request.user
        ctx['chat'] = chat
        ctx['form'] = self.modelForm
        user_id_message = self.model.objects.filter(members__username=request.user)
        ctx['unread_chat'] = user_id_message.model.objects.unread_chat(user=request.user).count()
        if request.is_ajax():
            response = HttpResponse(chat)
            response['chat'] = chat
            return response
        return render(request, self.template, ctx)
```

update_data_message.js

```
function start() {
    window.unread = window.setInterval(timer, 10000);
}

function timer() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#messages').html(data);
            console.log('complete');
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

window.onload = start();
```

message.html

```
{% if chat %}
            <div id="messages" class="panel">
                <div id="innerMessages">
                    {% for message in chat.message_set.all %}
                            {% include 'start_page/includes/dialog.html' with message_item=message %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
{% endif %}
```

Вот, что на выходе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, но в будущем его надо будет доработать.

utils.py

```
class ObjectMessageMixin:
    model = None
    modelForm = None
    template = None

    def get(self, request, chat_id):
        try:
            chat = self.model.objects.get(id=chat_id)
            if request.user in chat.members.all():
                chat.message_set.filter(is_read=False).exclude(author=request.user).update(is_read=True)
            else:
                chat = None
        except Chat.DoesNotExist:
            chat = None
        ctx = {}
        ctx['user'] = request.user
        ctx['chat'] = chat
        ctx['form'] = self.modelForm
        user_id_message = self.model.objects.filter(members__username=request.user)
        ctx['unread_chat'] = user_id_message.model.objects.unread_chat(user=request.user).count()
        if request.is_ajax():
            ctx['chat'] = chat
            return render(request, 'start_page/includes/dialog.html', ctx)
        return render(request, self.template, ctx)
```

update_data_message.js

```
function start() {
    window.unread = window.setInterval(timer, 5000);
}

function timer() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            var messages = document.getElementById('innerMessages');
            messages.innerHTML = data;
            console.log('complete');
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

window.onload = start();
```

немного переделал dialog.html в который и сгружаются данные о сообщениях

```
{% for message_item in chat.message_set.all %}
    {% with message_id=message_item.id %}
    <div class="list-group-item unreaded" {% if not message_item.is_read %}style="border-color: red"{% endif %}>
        <a href=""><img class="avatar-comment" src=""></a>
        <div class="reply-body">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li class="drop-left-padding">
                    <strong class="list-group-item-heading"><a href="">{{ message_item.author.username }}</a></strong>
                </li>
                <li class="pull-right text-muted"><small>{{ message_item.date_pub|utc }}</small></li>
            </ul>
            <div data-message-id="{{ message_id }}" data-message-slug="{{ message_item.slug_message }}" data-chat-id="{{ chat.id }}" class="item-message-id">
                <p id="{{ message_id }}">{{ message_item.message|safe }}</p>
                (...)
    </div>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Соответственно с message.html цикл снял, на доработку теперь остается сортировка сообщений, что бы на показ выходили не все, а часть, потому что если их будет например 1млн, то все будет очень плохо =)